# Is there a way to change jest.mock(<path>) automatically, when we modify the filename?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am using jest for testing and doing sth like this often:

```
jest.mock('../../<my_path_to_file>');
```

But when I decide to change the <my_path_to_file> name (rename the file basically), visual studio automatically detects imports in files to change and shows them, but I still have to manually change this jest.mock path.

Is there a way to automatically do this ?

Comment: I also wonder this. I have the same problem using Webstorm